# Yamaha YZ125K 1983 transmission bearings

Tags: motorcycle, transmission, yamaha

I'm restoring an engine and am unable to locate 3 gearbox bearings.

1. Identifying mark is either IXO or IKO. It is a needle roller bearing type and sits RHS crank case 1/3rd gear shaft.
2. Mark clearly shows 8304NX2, I think NTN is the manufacturer. I think this standard bearing type is called a groove bearing, anyway it sits on main sprocket/output shaft.
3. Mark appears to be Koyo 15 NQ2410D. Bearing sits LHS crank case 1st gear shaft.

I've managed to locate all the other bearings, except these three.  I'd appreciate any advice or help.

Answer (score 2):

**The bearing you are looking for are still available in the United States.**

Do a google search for "1983 Yamaha OEM parts"  You will see various Yamaha websites.  Goto one and chase your bike with the make/model/year and this will be the result, the ability to purchase the bearings.

***All of the transmission bearings for the bike are still available for purchase, new***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried contacting a large bearing distributor. Here in Australia I've used [CBC Bearings](http://www.conbear.com/) in the past to obtain transmission bearings.

Comment: I have good luck with getting bearing at these types of shops. They can measure and identify them even without markings. Plus they are usually cheaper than the dealer or conventional automotive sources.